# differential equation - with u(t) = cos(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given an differential equation : 
$ \frac{d^4y}{dt^4}+2\frac{d^3y}{dt^3}+3\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}+2\frac{dy}{dt}+y = u' + u$

With a transfer function: 
$H(s) = \frac{s+1}{s^4+2s^3+3s^2+2s+1}$

I am then trying to find the stationary answer y given u(t) = cos(t). I know that given u(t) = $e^{st}$ one would have $y(t) = H(s)*e^{st}$ but can you do something similar when u(t) = cos(t) ????

Comment: What is $u'$ and $u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply a sinusoidal input to a stable linear system with transfer function $H(s)$ then  the output will converge to a sinusoidal signal with the same frequency but with different amplitude and phase. Specifically, for an input $\cos(\omega t)$ the output will converge to $|H(j\omega)|\cos[\omega t+\arg(H(j\omega))]$. In your case $\omega=1$ and 
$$H(j1)=\frac{1+j}{1-2j-3+2j+1}=-(1+j)=\sqrt{2}e^{5\pi j/4}$$
so the output will be
$$\sqrt{2}\cos\left(t+\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)$$